# Term for means of communication

Tags: expressions

Considering such things as

- telephone calls {with/to/from} Raj
- text messages {with/to/from} Raj

I want a term that includes calls, texts, emails etc. I can come up only with

- communications with  Raj

but that seems too “unmemorable” and formal for the software user interface in which it must appear; in this case, the user has to remember the term himself.

Comment: All the users I have interacted with have no problems with the term "communication". In fact, the term "communication" is used even by clerks and admin staff in the US. If you are writing software for simple English or for a culture outside the US or Britain, you should consult your local English language experts, who are familiar with the mode of comprehension local to your culture.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of alternative nouns:
• *[interactions](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interaction#Noun)*, “conversations or exchanges between people”
• *[messages](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/message#Noun)* or *[messaging](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/messaging)*

Answer (score 1):

How about "electronic exchanges with Raj" ?

Comment: Or just exchanges... Gets my vote

Answer (score 1):

***"Contact" with Raj*** would encompass all forms of communication.  "Contact" can also be the hypernym if you need to break out the contact by type (e-mail, text, phone, direct, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Its a good idea to look around thesaurus when stuck in such situations. I recommend using the visual thesaurus for even more creative ideas.

1. *[Communication](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/communication?q=communication)* is fine. People are used to seeing this word. This would be the best choice in your case.
2. *[Conversation](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conversation?q=conversation)* is a good alternative, if you intend to suggest multiple forms
3. *[Interaction](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/interaction?q=interaction)*, would work too, but won't be my preference.
4. *[Visual Thesaurus](http://www.visualthesaurus.com/app/view)* This is a good tool to look around for other options. I liked *confab* from there. 
    [image]

Comment: Alas, that can’t be read because of the overlapping letters.

Comment: :)
Edited the image. but still can't get them space out to post it here.